# Private Routing authentication with Reactn and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-signin

I am stuck in a part implementing private routing

So here is what I want to ultimately achieve:

I would like to sign in with Google, and once I am signed in I would like to go to a private route page, if I am signed out, I should not be able to do that.

For the code part:

a class to track login state (true/false):

```
class Auth {
    isAuthenticated: boolean
    constructor(){
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
    }

login(){
    this.isAuthenticated= true;
}

logout(){
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
}

isLoggedIn(){
    return this.isAuthenticated;
}

}

export default new Auth();
```

A summarised snippet for the google login:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin, GoogleLogout} from 'react-google-login'; 
import auth from './auth';

 login (response: any) {

   if(response.accessToken){
     this.setState(state => ({
       isLogined: true,
       userName: response.profileObj.givenName + ' ' + response.profileObj.familyName
     }));
     this.refreshTokenSetup(response);
     auth.login();
   }

 }

render() { //this is what is rendered (what users see) in the react web app pahge
   return (
   <div>
    <GoogleLogin
         clientId={ CLIENT_ID } 
         buttonText='Login' 
         onSuccess={ this.login} 
         isSignedIn={true}
         onFailure={ this.handleLoginFailure }
         cookiePolicy={ 'single_host_origin' }
         responseType='code,token' 
       />
     }
```

and finally, my protected route:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Route, Router, Redirect, RouteProps} from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from './auth';

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<RouteProps> = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    if (!Component) return null;
    return (
        <div>
            <Route {...rest} render={props => (
                auth.isAuthenticated ?
                <Component {...props} />: 
                <Redirect to="/" />
            )} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

According to a tutorial I followed, if they set `this.isAuthenticated=true` in ClassX, the value is still true when they import auth and access it in ClassA, I don't know how since I assume new instances are created every time they import?

My question is: is it possible to edit the value to "true" in one class, and access it from another, if so how?

If not, any suggestions on what can I do to fix my problem?

Comment: I would implement auth as a `useAuth` hook so that you are subscribed to updates of a global value.  Look into the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and how it can be used here.

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks !